# VB.NET Multiple titles at same height in a windows forms chart

Tags: vb.net, winforms, charts, data-visualization

How do I put multiple titles into a chart at the same height?

No matter what parameters I choose I get results similar to this. My last try before asking here.

The screen shot shows the titles with a backcolor to prove what I expected.
Whenever I add 2 titles WinForms automatically puts them in different heights.

The 3. line is custom added to show you what I want to have as a result.

I could write a method but it should react to resize events and solving this with docking or alignments is preferred.

[image: titles]

So right now the titles are inside the chartarea because I was fiddling around with DockingOffsets etc. I want them to be on top of the chartarea.

Here is my code:

```
Friend Function CreateTitle(ByVal titleName As TitleName, ByVal chart As Chart) As Title
        Dim font As Font = Nothing
        Dim foreColor As Color = Nothing
        Dim backColor As Color = Nothing
        Dim alignment As ContentAlignment = Nothing
        Dim dockingOffset As Integer
        Dim name As String = String.Empty
        Dim titleText As String = String.Empty
        Dim dockedToChartArea As String = String.Empty
        Dim docking As Docking = Nothing

        ' Default settings
        font = New Font("Arial", 12)
        foreColor = color.blue
        dockingOffset = 0
        dockedToChartArea = chart.ChartAreas(0).Name

        ' Custom settings
        Select Case titleName
            Case ChartControls.TitleName.ComponentName
                name = TITLENAME_COMP
                titleText = chart.Name
                alignment = ContentAlignment.BottomLeft
                dockingOffset = 0
                docking = DataVisualization.Charting.Docking.Top
                backColor = Color.Coral

            Case ChartControls.TitleName.TrafficLight
                name = TITLENAME_TRAFFICLIGHT
                titleText = "+34.6% / 1800 €"
                alignment = ContentAlignment.TopRight
                dockingOffset = 0
                docking = DataVisualization.Charting.Docking.Top
                backColor = Color.Beige
        End Select

        Dim title As New Title(titleText)
        title.Name = name
        title.Font = font
        title.ForeColor = foreColor
        title.BackColor = backColor
        title.Alignment = alignment
        title.Position = New ElementPosition()
        title.Docking = docking
        title.DockingOffset = dockingOffset
        title.DockedToChartArea = dockedToChartArea

        Return title
    End Function
```

I call this method twice with different parameters and add them to my Titles collection.

Comment: My temp solution is adding a dummy title to get some space between chart and chartarea. Put a panel around the chart as well as adding 2 labels to that panel. I set the location of the labels depending on the panels width and labels width. If you are interested in the solution I will put it as answer but its not my preferred way. Works fine anyway.

Comment: If it works, what is wrong? Are you anticipating issues with it? If so, that would be important to know in terms of providing you a solution that takes those anticipated issues into consideration.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it. But it is a "hacked" solution because I use plain old labels and position them as needed instead of the chart titles collection. So a non "hacked" solution is preferable. At least that's what I would prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my workaround because of requirements. It would have been very time consuming to make my workaround work for 1 .. n charts that differ in size depending on the amount of charts because then the labels would need a different size and position. So I had to find a better solution.

I have a Enum with 2 different title. The following properties are important.

- Backcolor = Transparent
- Only for one title choose a custom position. This turns the property "Position.Auto" to false. Take a look at my if clause at the end. So because the other property "Position.Auto" stays true because you don't manually change it you can simply assign a offset while bringing the other title manually to the same height.

.

```
`Friend Function CreateTitle(ByVal titleName As TitleName) As Title
            Dim titleText As String = String.Empty
            Dim alignment As ContentAlignment

        ' Custom settings
        Select Case titleName
            Case ChartControls.TitleName.Title1
                titleText = "Title1"
                alignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft

            Case ChartControls.TitleName.Title2
                titleText = "Title2"
                alignment = ContentAlignment.TopRight
        End Select

        Dim title As New Title()
        title.Text = titleText
        title.Font = New Font("Arial", 12)
        title.BackColor = Color.Transparent
        If titleName.Equals(CCT.ChartControls.TitleName.Title2) Then
            title.Position = New ElementPosition(0, 3, 94, 5)
        Else
            title.DockingOffset = 0
        End If
        title.Alignment = alignment

        Return title
    End Function`
```

Looks like this: 2 titles on same height.
[image: Result]